# import class with dependencies on different classes in different files

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, import, node-modules

I am wondering what is best practice to add multiple instances of another class from another file that has additional dependencies from other classes in other files. Furthermore, what do I have to consider when calling instances from such a randomly path structure:

```
index.js
|_ .../ParentClass/ParentClass.js
  d|_ /ParentClass/ChildClass.js
   | d|_ .../AnotherClass.js
  d|_ .../AnyOtherClass/Class.js
 
 d := depends on
```

Edited:

So far, I tried to import and create new instances from [this repository](https://github.com/trekhleb/javascript-algorithms) by doing the following:

- added a line in `package.json` in the top directory with `"type": "module",`
- `import ClassName from "./path/to/Class"` or `import ClassName from "packageName"` wont resolve modules throwing Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '...' imported from ....js.
- `import ClassName from "./path/to/Class.js"` throws an error telling that ParentClass.js is not available as module since the underlying classes have import statements without the .js extension like `import ParentClass from "./path/to/ParentClass/ParentClass/"`

How do I solve this problem without modifiying all underlying Class.js-files by adding .js in all the import statements?

I asked my question in a slightly different manner in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73426877/importing-a-class-with-multiple-dependencies-in-node-js-results-in-syntaxerror?noredirect=1#comment129669305_73426877) without much resolution. Please, does someone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: @PeterJames Thank you for your answser. I believe the problem is different since the error here makes clear that either: import definition is wrong OR package is missing.

Comment: at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:932:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:978:18)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1080:11)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:251:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:79:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'

Comment: The problem is not the same, because headers and environment variables are not involved.

Comment: Interestingly enough the following statement `import ClassName from '/path/to/Class.js'` (note the .js extension) error says the parent module couldn't load. I conclude that an import statement of a class does not seem to have a .js extension. Class.js does import the partent module without the .js extension.

Comment: more precisely the import statements in Class.js has no .js-file extension in its import statements, so it doesn't direcetly point to the depending js-files. How do I solve this problem without modifiying all respective Class.js-files by adding .js in all the import statements?